# How to access to app default gesture recognizers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, view, uigesturerecognizer

I have created simple single view application and added just one button to view.
Next i used next code to determine all subviews and it's gesture recognizers:

```
-(void) debug:(UIView*) view{
    for(UIGestureRecognizer* g in view.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        NSLog(@"base view gr=%@ gr_view=%@",NSStringFromClass ([g class]),g.view);
    }
    for (UIView* sub in view.subviews) {

        NSLog(@"%@.subview=%@",NSStringFromClass ([view class]),NSStringFromClass ([sub class]));

        for(UIGestureRecognizer* g in sub.gestureRecognizers)
        {
            NSLog(@"          | gr=%@ gr_view=%@",NSStringFromClass ([g class]),g.view);
        }
        [self debug:sub];
    }
}
```

But the log shows NO ONE gesture recognizer in existing view and it's subviews. I wold like to have access to default app gesture recognizers, how can i do this?

Comment: have you added any guesture recognizers on the view? if not than i think that is the solution

Comment: why you need this...? anyways UIGesturRecognizer and tapAction of UIButton are two different things..

Comment: You don't need UIGestureRecognizers to receive and interpret touches; they are just there for the programmer to use if they want to implement certain kinds of common gestures (for example, swiping or pinching).  UIButtons do not have their own UIGestureRecognizers (by default) and UIViews do not have UIGestureRecognizers by default either.  It's up to you to add UIGestureRecognizers if you need them.

Comment: No i have not added my gesture recognizer due to the fact that i wold like to have access to default app gesture recognizer. I suppose that in app there are some default gesture recognizers, when you tap the button it fires tapAction, that is why i try to have access to default gesture recognizer (possible in future i would like to switch off default gesture recognizer and assign to this view my custom gesture recognizer).

Comment: For example i  have TableView which works in editing mode (i have ReorderingControl on it) and i wold like to reorder cells in the table, but some times instead of reordering cells - my table view scrolls when i tap and drug ReorderingControl, i'd like to disable scrolling for a some time, to perform it i try to access to default gesture recognizer and switch off it, but i can't do it.

Comment: These aren't gesture recognizers. If you want to stop scrolling you just set the tableview scrollEnabled property to NO. Or you can disable button taps by disabling it (enabled property) or set userInteraction to NO. Without a clear goal no one will be able to tell you how to do lots of different things.